# Is this set $\{ p(x): x\in \operatorname{bco} A\}$ bounded in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

$\newcommand{\bco}{\operatorname{bco}}$Here are some terminologies.

**Definition.** Let $X$ be a real vector space and let $A\subseteq X$. The **balanced-convex hull** of $A$, denoted $\bco A$, is the intersection of all balanced-convex subsets of $X$ that contain $A$.

**Remark.**  Let $X$ be a real vector space and let $A\subseteq X$. Then
$$\bco A=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i: n\in\mathbb{N},x_i\in A, a_i\in\mathbb{R}\mbox{ and }\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|\le1  \right\}.$$

Some details of the remark are found in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376007/about-balanced-convex-hull-of-a-set). Suppose that $p: X\to \mathbb{R}$ is a seminorm on $X$. Let
$$B=\{p(x): x\in \bco A\}.$$
Is $B$ a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}?$ If it is, can you please explain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B$ is bounded if and only if the set $S:=\{p(x),x\in A\}$ is bounded. Indeed, if $S$ is not bounded, no chance to expect $B$ to be bounded. If $S$ is bounded, then 
$$p\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_ix_i\right)\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|p(x_i)\leqslant \sup_{x\in A}p(x)\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|\leqslant \sup_{x\in A}p(x),$$
where the first inequality follows from the fact that $p$ is a semi-norm.

Comment: Nice characterization for the set $B$. Its great! Thanks